# How do I make a binary counter with the <ol> tag?

Tags: html, css

I thought that I could do the following:

```
<ol style = "type:numeric; glyphs: '0' '1';">
    <li> Item 0 </li>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
</ol>
```

to produce a list that counted in binary. That is, the above example should have produced:

> *0*. Item 0
>
> *1*. Item 1
>
> *10*. Item 2

But alas, it did no such thing. Firefox just ignored my style suggestions.

I was reading about this on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/ (section 8.1.2)

But clearly I've misread / misunderstood the specification. Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for the formatting clean up! How did you do that?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/lists.html, that gives good samples of what you need, as well as covering browser support.

Comment: @BRivera Try editing your question again and take a look at the markdown :)

Comment: Just click the orange question mark on the right top of the editor to see formatting guide.

Comment: @AdrianWragg that tells me that "binary" won't work in, say, FF as a list-style-type, but I thought I could force a counter à la glyphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` and `glyphs` properties go in side a `@counter-style` declaration, so you need to define counter style then use it.

```
@counter-style mybinary {
    type: numeric;
    glyphs: '0' '1' '2';
}

<ol style = "list-style-type:mybinary;">
    <li> Item 0 </li>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
</ol>
```

I don't think any browser implements this though as this is all I found on it besides the working draft and this line from MDN

> [CSS Lists and Counters Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/#list-style-type)   Working Draft   Adds support for  and adds identifiers used in @counter-style rules to keywords.
>   These changes are not yet reflected on this page as no browser currently implements them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it visible in every browser, you need to do it with another language (javascript/jquery, or with something comming from your server)

In the end, you just need to have something like that :
http://jsfiddle.net/KdhxX/

```
<ol>
  <li value="0"> Item 0 </li>
  <li value="1"> Item 1 </li>
  <li value="10"> Item 2 </li>
</ol>
```

with the value inserted inside your "li" populated by javascript, or your server-side language